# logback does not write to file

Tags: java, logging, logback

I have an app with the following logback config

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<configuration debug="true">

    <appender name="STDOUT" class="ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender">
        <encoder>
            <pattern>%d{HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%thread] %-5level{5} %logger - %msg%n</pattern>
        </encoder>
    </appender>

    <appender name="FILE" class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender">
        <file>${HOME}/app.log</file>
        <rollingPolicy class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.TimeBasedRollingPolicy">
            <fileNamePattern>${HOME}/old/app-%d{yyyy-MM-dd}.%i.gz</fileNamePattern>
            <timeBasedFileNamingAndTriggeringPolicy
                    class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.SizeAndTimeBasedFNATP">
                <maxFileSize>100MB</maxFileSize>
            </timeBasedFileNamingAndTriggeringPolicy>
            <maxHistory>14</maxHistory>
        </rollingPolicy>
             ch.qos.logback.classic.encoder.PatternLayoutEncoder by default -->
        <encoder>
            <pattern>%d{HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%thread] %-5level %logger{5} - %msg%n</pattern>
        </encoder>
    </appender>

    <appender name="EXCEPTIONS" class="com.software.nagibator.emulator.logging.ExceptionsAppender">
        <connectionSource class="ch.qos.logback.core.db.JNDIConnectionSource">
            <jndiLocation>jdbc/AppExceptions</jndiLocation>
        </connectionSource>
    </appender>

    <logger name="FileLogger" level="DEBUG" additivity="false">
        <appender-ref ref="FILE" />
    </logger>

    <logger name="ExceptionsLogger" level="DEBUG" additivity="false">
        <appender-ref ref="EXCEPTIONS" />
    </logger>

    <root level="DEBUG">
        <appender-ref ref="STDOUT" />
    </root>

</configuration>
```

I use this config on two ubuntu servers. On the first server the config works as expected (it writes the log to file). However, on the second server logback does not write the log to file.

Is there something wrong with my config or is the error elsewhere in the project?

Comment: Included referenced pastebin config file content, fixed wording.

Answer (score 0):

```
</rollingPolicy>
  ch.qos.logback.classic.encoder.PatternLayoutEncoder by default -->
 <encoder>
...
```

It's look like you miss < !-- before comment in xml.